# Is communication between Google cloud SQL and GCE instances are encrypted?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have an application connecting to Google cloud SQL from a GCE instance. Is the traffic encrypted between MySQL instance and my GCE instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Customer data is encrypted when in Google's internal network. External connections can be encrypted using SSL. You can find more info at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#encryption)